# how to draw dynamic series in Highchart based on data

Tags: highcharts

I want add number of  series based on the data. Example sometimes for the same request, High-chart may include 2 series or 4 series.

Ex:

```
Request 1
[[ser1,ser2,datetime],[ser1,ser2,datetime]]

Request 2
[[ser1,ser2, ser3,ser4, datetime],[ser1,ser2, ser3,ser4, datetime]]
```

Where "datetime" is x-axis values

Could you please suggest me how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your data to the right format in the preprocessing.

```
var json = [
    [2, 4, 1500284119000],
    [10, 20, 1500284141000]
  ],
  series = [],
  each = Highcharts.each,
  len;

each(json, function(items, i) {

  len = items.length;

  each(items, function(item, j) {

    if (j < len - 1) {
      if (i === 0) { // create series structure
        series.push({
          data: []
        });
      }

      series[j].data.push({
        x: items[len - 1],
        y: item
      })
    }
  });

});
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/hx97ak00/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to change the response structure if your xAxis is a datetime.
better include the timestamp along with data as below

```
seriesData = [[timestamp1, val1],[timestamp2, val],[timestamp3, val3],......]
```

now your request looks like this

```
Request 1
[seriesData1, seriesData2, seriesData3,seriesData4]

Request 2
[seriesData1, seriesData2, seriesData3, seriesData4, seriesData5, seriesData6, seriesData7,seriesData8]
```

I think you went to have a separate array for datetime because you have diffent number of series of data for 2 different timestamps.

In the above mentioned approach. you can directly feed the series section with the incoming response of the request.

Hope this will help you.